# Update jsonb with column from other table

Tags: jsonb

How do I update a jsonb field on one of the tables with selecting a column from another table, which is not of jsonb type, and matching on `id` column on both tables.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What error do you face?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, see the Help page, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also refer to [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).